# CSS background image is rendered blurred and not entirely

Tags: css

I am having trouble trying to place an image as background on my website. 
Here's how the original image looks like:

[image]

And here's how the image appears on my website (from Chrome):

[image]

As you see, the picture is not entirely rendered (clearly seen looking at the coffee cup and notebook display).

Here's the css that I use:

```
 body {
    overflow:hidden;
    background: url('/static/media/images/welcome1.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover; 
    background-size: cover;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please also provide the original image ? Everything seems fine on your screenshot

Comment: Looks like both images URL are same!! 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOCqf.jpg'

Comment: Fixed the image urls

Comment: And how should I fixed it ? Yes, you are right. It's blurred

Comment: Do you mean that I should change the size of the pic itself (say, in Photoshop) ?

Comment: Based on the screenshot reference shared, try to find similar image whose dimension is min. 1365x585 pixels and above. Stretching the smaller dimension image will definetly blur the image

Comment: I added my comments as an answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using a too small version of the picture which becomes blurry when it's enlarged beyond its own size.

Use a larger version if possible: That's a stock photo from pixabay or something, isn't it? Go there and look if there is a larger version available (usually there is), and use that instead.

BTW: I reread the question: You say you are missing parts of the coffe cup and the notebook display: That's due to the different width/heigth proportion of the image part that is displayed. This happens automatically when you use `background-size: cover` to fill the whole available space with the background image. (The first part of my answer referred to the blurryness)

Answer (score 3):

you are using "cover", thats why image gets blur when page rendered. If you use images with higher resulotions than the screen, problem will be solved. Just try to find bigger images than your screen and try it with developer tools. You will see and understand the difference.

Comment: that's what I am saying all the time... (in the comments) ;-)

Comment: I didnt saw your comment while i am posting.. After all we all here for same reason. Sorry dude. :)

Comment: So, looks like I have to accept Johannes' answer, right ?:)

Comment: I dont care as long as you get your answer. I dont have big ego :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try 'background-size: 100%;' it background always will width 100%

Example - https://jsfiddle.net/grinmax_/g5sht11p/

HTML

```
<div class="container"></div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/SK2W1.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```