# Background image is blurry/pixelated on CSS

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I'm trying to make a Login System using Python flask and MySQL. I tried styling the html templates using CSS and I made it look good but the background image is blurry for some reason. I tried doing "image-rendering:" but it didn't work. Is there any fix to this?

**Code:**

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: url('/static/background2.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

[image: This is how the background image looks.]

Comment: If you open your background image in a browser tab. Does it look blurry there. How is its resolution?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the resolution of the picture. It seems like your picture is of low resolution and that is why it is blur when you try to expand it. If your resolution is ok try writing background-size:100%; instead of background-size: cover;............ I hope this works :)

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately. My resolution is 1080p its fine.

Answer (score 0):

The original image may have a large size, and when you combine it into the website background, it zooms in, which causes the blurry image.

Comment: It's 1920x1080? What do I do?

Comment: Here are some links that I believe can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18677983/how-to-prevent-the-background-image-from-getting-blurry https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42529379/css-background-image-is-rendered-blurred-and-not-entirely/42529554

Comment: Unfortunately I already have tried those and none of it worked.

Comment: Here are a few links that i found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29599794/how-to-sharpen-an-image-in-css. https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/clear-image/27027/2.   https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-change-image-size-in-html

Answer (score -1):

It is probably the image that is low quality. Try another image!

Comment: how could i have known that

Comment: yeah i should've mentioned it in the question